# How can you create wildcard routes on Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, lumen, fastroute

Let's say I have a controller called TeamsController. Controller has following method, that returns all teams user has access to.

```
public function findAll(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
  //...
}
```

Then I have bunch of other controllers with the same method. I would like to create a single route, that would work for all controllers, so I would not need to add a line for each controller every time I create a new controller.

I am unable to catch the controller name from URI. This is what I have tried.

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () use ($router) {
    // This works
    //$router->get('teams', 'TeamsController@findAll');
    
    // This just returns TeamsController@findAll string as a response
    $router->get('{resource}', function ($resource) {
        return ucfirst($resource) . 'Controller@findAll';
    });
});
```

Comment: First of all, that sounds like a bad idea. Routes are (and should be) stored in the cache, so I'm not sure that would even work. Your code returns a string, so it's normal that it shows the string as response. the controller function is never called.

Comment: You are going through a lot of time and effort to save you adding one line every time a new resource is added to your API which I am guessing is not frequent. Do you really find this to be a good use of your time?

Comment: @GertB. So they would not be cached, if using Closures? That was what I was also thinking. I guess its better to list all routes then. This is first Lumen / Laravel project in our company so just getting started. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You return a string instead of calling a controller action:
I believe Laravel loads the controllers this way (not tested)

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () use ($router) {
  $router->get('{resource}', function ($resource) {
    $app = app();
    $controller = $app->make('\App\Http\Controllers\'. ucfirst($resource) . 'Controller');
    return $controller->callAction('findAll', $parameters = array());
 });
});
```

But again, I don't really think it's a good idea.